# How to set innerHTML in foreach?

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

I want this code each of tag  innerhtml change, if `<a>facebook</a>` set to `<a><i class='fab fa-facebook'></i></a>`.

```
<main class="non">
 <div class="author-desc">
  <a href="#">facebook</a>, <a href="#">twitter</a>, <a href="#">github</a>
 </div>
</main>
```

And my javascript is pass in queryselectorall, but after foreach idk how to do.

```
<script>
  let sosmed = document.querySelector(".author-desc");
  let sosmeds = sosmed.querySelectorAll("a");
  sosmeds.forEach(function (element) {
  if (element.innerHTML === "facebook")(function(set){
    element.innerHTML = "<i class='fab fa-facebook'></i>"
  });
});
</script>
```

I want answer with the specific explanation. What i can do for that?

and i was stuck in this code, the inner html of a doesn't change.

```
sosmeds.forEach(function (element) {
  if (element.innerHTML === "facebook")(function(set){
    element.innerHTML = "<i class='fab fa-facebook'></i>"
  });
```

Comment: Apart from there being a missing `>` for the `<i>` please explain in more detail what your problem is

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: the foreach function doesn't work.

Comment: start by making the `<i>` html valid.

Comment: what are you trying to do in the `forEach` ?

Comment: You defined a function in an if, makes no sense. Again..... what are you trying to do? Replace the text with the icon?

Comment: You need to also explain what *"I want this code text to my own text."* means in more detail. Nobody is fully understanding your objective or what is going wrong or errors encountered

Comment: i try to set if innerhtml is facebook, the innerhtml change to `<i class='fab fa-facebook'></i>` but doesn't work.

Comment: You have a function declaration, makes no sense, there should not be the `function(set){` You are defining a function that is not executed... hence why it does nothing. Your developer tools should be showing errors.

Comment: Oh i see, the function is not executed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of the function that does nothing and fix syntax errors.

```js
let sosmeds = document.querySelectorAll(".author-desc a");
sosmeds.forEach(function(element) {
  if (element.innerHTML === "facebook") {
    element.innerHTML = "<i class='fa fa-facebook'></i>";
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<main class="non">
  <div class="author-desc">
    <a href="#">facebook</a>, <a href="#">twitter</a>, <a href="#">github</a>
  </div>
</main>
```